# How can I enable the "Publish to SharePoint..." option in SketchFlow?

Tags: expression-blend, expression-sketchflow

My MSDN subscription provides Expression Blend 4, but not Ultimate.  I received a 60 day trial of SketchFlow which I'm using for evaluation.  However the "Publish to SharePoint..." option is disabled.  Can anyone tell me how to enable this functionality?

Comment: I think it's a feature deliberately left disabled in the trial version since it's not required to test the overall functionality of the app. However it doesn't state this in their documentation, you might try asking in the official Expression forum. Best of luck! http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/threads

Comment: No problem, I especially rely on Chuck & Brian over there for Expression answers quite often and they're always very helpful. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference to others.

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/20deaec5-4762-411b-b111-84d5c8b5fae2